# The meaning of "header td"

Tags: html, css, html-table, semantics

I'm not really familiar with these kind of functions, but could anyone explain to me what "header td" does and if it's really necessary in CSS? I have a header that doesn't work properly. I tried to delete this part from the CSS, but then the whole header is gone.

CSS code of the header:

```
/* Header
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#header-wrap {
    background:url(HeaderLuminescentLarge.png)no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.wsite-custom-background #header-wrap {
    background: none;
}

#header {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
} 

#header td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you asking how selectors work? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: That is not a function, it's a CSS selector.. Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp

Comment: I don't understand what the code does with the header. What does the "td" part mean?

Comment: It targets a `<td>` element inside an element with the id "header".

Comment: And if removing it breaks the layout, you can probably guess the answer to the "[is it] really necessary" question.

Answer (score 1):

`#header td` selects all `<td>` elements inside an element having `id` as `header`.

You've specified `height:100%;` for the header, but its parent (`#header-wrap`) doesn't seem to have a height set explicitly, hence height in `%` won't be applied.

Once you removed the style rule

```
#header td {
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: left;
 height: 500px;
}
```

the child elements also don't have a height set, which is why the header suddenly disappeared (*its height will be `0`*).

Comment: Okay, thank you.
I tried to make my header fits the size of any screen, no matter how big it is. But I can't seem to change the height of the "header td" section so that it expand automatically. (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: the default value of `height` property is `auto`. If you want an element to expand automatically then no need to set a `height` attribute. but then like i said above if there's no content it won't be visible. You can set the `min-height` property to set a minimum default width...

Comment: Hmm, could you maybe show it where to put the "auto height" and the "min-height" properties in the CSS code?

Comment: Hmm... could you improve your question with the corresponding `HTML` in question or a demo of the issue you're having..?

Comment: I hope this works: http://jsfiddle.net/Noukster/4Abmj/
I made the site with an online builder called Weebly, so the CSS was already there.

Comment: @Noukster that just got me more confused... no idea what you want with it..? what's the problem with that fiddle..?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.. I thought the complete CSS would be useful. There also are more than one HTML files, so I don't know which one I need to have.
Sorry for the confusion.